# Line break in watermark

Tags: context, watermark

I want to add a watermark to my document and am using the this example code show on context-wiki:

```
\setupcolors[state=start]

\defineoverlay[WatermarkOverlay]
              [{\framed[frame=off,foregroundcolor=gray]
               {\scale[sx=12,sy=12]
               {\rotate[rotation=20.0]{Draft}}}}]

\setupbackgrounds[page][background=WatermarkOverlay]
```

Instead of the word `Draft`, I would like add a number of words with a line break. For example, `This is a long watermark` but I would like to put a line break after the word `a`. I have tried adding `\\` and `\break` and `\newline` between `a` and `long` but they don't seem to work.

The code I have tried is:

\setupcolors[state=start]

```
\defineoverlay[WatermarkOverlay]
              [{\framed[frame=off,foregroundcolor=gray]
               {\scale[sx=12,sy=12]
               {\rotate[rotation=20.0]{this is a \\ long watermark}}}}]

\setupbackgrounds[page][background=WatermarkOverlay]
```

The watermark does not have a line break in the text when compiled.

Comment: Please complete your code so it can be compiled. What does `don't seem to work` mean? Do you get an error? Is the break ignored?

Comment: Added code. No error but no line break either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stick your watermark into a `framed` so the lines break:

```
\defineoverlay[WatermarkOverlay]
          [{\framed[frame=off,foregroundcolor=gray]
           {\scale[sx=3,sy=3]
           {\rotate[rotation=20.0]{\framed[align=middle,frame=off]{this is a \\ long watermark}}}}}]

\setupbackgrounds[page][background=WatermarkOverlay]
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: The outer frame is redundant. You could just add `foregroundcolor` key to the inner frame. I would have also use a `foregroundstyle` with a bigger font rather than scaling the box (I know the OP copied it from the wiki)

Comment: Aditya, you are right of course - I wanted my solution to be "minimally invasive." OP had some elements toward what he was trying to do, so I just copied his code.

Comment: @Aditya: To aid my understanding, how should I have done this. I have tried removing the outer frame but then the watermark appears on the top left of the page.

Comment: @pdoak: This is how I would do it. First define a new framed for the watermark: `\defineframed[WatermarkFrame] [align=middle, frame=off, foregroundcolor=gray, foregroundstyle=\tfd]` and then use `\defineoverlay[WatermarkOverlay][{\rotate[rotation=20.0]{\WatermarkFrame{this is a \\ long watermark}}}]`

Comment: @Aditya: Thank you, that's very helpful in furthering my understanding. When setting the font size with `\tfd`, is there a way to set say an arbitrary font size, say 48pt.  `foregroundstyle` does not seem to accept anything other than `\...`.

Comment: @pdoak: use `foregroundstyle={\switchtobodyfont[48pt]}`.

Comment: @Aditya : thank you. Where would I find out that the syntax for 'foreground style' takes '{}' instead of the just '\' that you used in your first answer.

Comment: @pdoak: That is basic TeX. It we tried `\setupframed[foregroundstyle=\switchtobodyfont[48pt]]`, then the parser will match the starting `[` (immediately after `setupframed` with the ending `]` of `[48pt]`. Enclosing the entire option in `{...}` hides the inner `]` from the TeX parser. You can add `{...}` around all options, but it is redundant in most cases.

Comment: @Aditya : Tank you for the explanation.